# Rails Routing Issue (using c9.io as dev)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

So I have a weird routing issue that I cannot seem to solve, any advice would be great.

This is the process:

1. Create new account
2. Submit: Username, email, password, password confirmation

Now two things have happened, and I cant tell why the difference occurs.
First; This is what it should do.

3. Routes to the next stage of capturing more User related details, Busines Name, Contact No, etc.

   - the 2nd page is users/id/edit (so i can finish the user account details)
   - this is correct, and works

Sometimes, with the same user details for stage one. It does this:
Routes to users/show/id

So what I understand at the moment, when it fails on step 2, the account creation, the controller tells the system to render /users/show

Now that's not meant to happen, as  I have the controller setup that if @users.save fails (in the Create method for user controller), the system should render 'new' (users/new) with an error message being displayed. (Like, password doesn't meet the validation requirements). But, it doesn't do this, its routing to users/show.

Once upon a time, at the early stage, @users.save if successful, would route to users/show (used as a test, to view the created account details) but this was in version 1. And that route hasn't existed in weeks. But, even then, if i check the database for the saved user details, its not there. So the route to users/show on success, isn't being pulled when the save is a success. Meaning its rendering on the failure.

It gets more interesting though, with the fact that I can enter the EXACT SAME details (Name, Email, Password) and it works, but then sometimes it doesn't.

Also, I reset the migration database when trying to create the same account to test it. So its not breaking at the Unique validation. And even when I do break it with that, I get an error saying "Email already in use" - which is exactly what I want it to do.

More information:
I'm using a Cloud Based dev environment (www.c9.io).
The problem happens 1 in 3 times - without changing the input data.

Suspicions: The VM being hosted to support my environment (By c9) is not pulling the live code through as it should, and some old controller code is being initialized instead. So it's operating on 50% new 50% old code.

Or, am I missing something with how Rails uses REST/Nested routing.

Comment: There are some issues with C9 in the US right now. For updates on that situation, see http://status.c9.io. This may or may not be related.

Comment: I just tweeted at you, asking if about how the VM's cache code. I love using your dev environment, and would continue if this is resolved quickly. Hopefully it is. Thank you for the response

Comment: This should be fixed now. If it is not, please contact support@c9.io :)